# MYSQL Counting duplicate ID's WHERE booleans are false as TOTAL column, not counting total = 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a DB for a library system, where each copy of a book has a unique ID.
When trying to create a view, listing each title and the total amount of available (*not archived or already borrowed*) books with that title, I'm facing the problem that it **won't list a title with no available books**.
The columns deciding whether the book is borrowed or archived function as booleans, the view won't count them if either is true.

I want it to display the amount as 0 if all the copies are unavailable.
[image]

I've tried multiple different ways of making views for this, but end up with the same issue, or a view that is making me lose track of what I'm doing because of its' complexity.

```
CREATE VIEW `visitorbookview` AS
SELECT 
    bo.id,
    bo.title,
    bo.writer,
    bo.description,
    ca.name AS category,
    pu.name AS publisher,
    bo.dewey,
    bo.ebook,
    COUNT(0) AS amount
FROM
    `booknumber` `bn`
    JOIN `books` `bo` ON `bn`.`books_id` = `bo`.`id`
    JOIN `publisher` `pu` ON `pu`.`id` = `bo`.`publisher_idpublisher`
    JOIN `category` `ca` ON `ca`.`id` = `bo`.`category_idcategory`
WHERE
    ((`bn`.`borrowed` = 0)
        AND (`bn`.`archived` = 0))
GROUP BY `bn`.`books_id`
```

CREATES

| id | title | writer | description | category | publisher | dewey | ebook | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kalle och C | Roald Dahl | - | Barn | Rabén Sjögren | 800 | no | 1 |
| 2 | Harry Potte | J.K Rowling | - | Ungdom | Bloomsbury Publ | 800 | no | 10 |

The problem is that if I mark the last copy of book 1 as archived/borrowed, it won't show in the view anymore. I get why it happens, i just don't know how to correct the issue.

Row 5 changed to archived = 1

| id | books_id | borrowed | archived | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Empty |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Broken |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Empty |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | Empty |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 | TEST |
| 6 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 7 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 9 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 10 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 11 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 12 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 13 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 14 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| 15 | 2 | 0 | 0 | Empty |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Produces following result

| id | title | writer | description | category | publisher | dewey | ebook | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Harry Potter and the Philosophers stone | J.K Rowling | - | Ungdom | Bloomsbury Publishing Ltd. | 800 | no | 10 |

Comment: Please don't post your data as images, copy it into the question body instead.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT bo.id, bo.title, bo.writer, bo.description,
       ca.name AS category, pu.name AS publisher,
       bo.dewey, bo.ebook,
       COUNT(bn.bookid) AS amount
FROM books bo LEFT JOIN
     booknumber bn
     ON bn.books_id = bo.id AND
        bn.borrowed = 0 AND
        bn.archived = 0 LEFT JOIN
     publisher pu
     ON pu.id = bo.publisher_idpublisher LEFT JOIN
     category ca
     ON ca.id = bo.category_idcategory
GROUP BY bo.id, bo.title, bo.writer, bo.description,
         ca.name, pu.name,
         bo.dewey, bo.ebook;
```

Notes:

- You have parentheses in the `FROM` clause that are unnecessary and just make the query harder to read.
- You are putting all identifiers in backticks.  That just makes the query harder to write and to read.
- The default name for a column reference is the column name, so `bo.title as title` is redundant.
- The conditions in the `WHERE` clause need to be in the `ON` clauses because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the over use of backticks, mysql workbench generated them when i looked at my create statment. Same thing with all of the aliases, and parentheses.

I tried your solution but it doesn't quite give me the right output. It shows book 1 with amount: 1

Comment: @JohnRotkins . . . You need to count something from one of the other tables.  I fixed that.